# Performance Issue with SQL Server query in a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows, service

We are facing a performance issue with a stored procedure called from a .net application (Windows service) using Microsoft enterprise library 3.0. The SQL Server procedure simply checks the existence of a record, and if it doesn't exist, it insert the record into the table, otherwise it just returns them.

There are the following columns in the table:

```
create table AlarmLog 
(
    Id                   bigint
    MessageId            int
    MessageTime          datetime
    ControllerId         int
    InterfaceHardwareId  int
    IDType               int
    MapId                int
    RelatedEmployeeId    int
    RelatedCardId        int
);
```

The `Id` column is the primary key and has the clustered index on it.

As a business rule, while inserting record it in, we need to ensure that, the combination (`MessageId, MessageTime, ControllerId, InterfaceHardwareId, IDType, MapId`) is unique. Hence, we put an `if exists` condition to check if the combination already exists. This condition checking is taking the long time.

We have tried adding, a non-clustered index on `MessageId, MessageTime, ControllerId, InterfaceHardwareId, IDType, MapId`.

On a test server in our lab, there are about 30,00,000 records and even if the condition is in place it inserts quite faster about 400+ rows per min using the same .net service. We have also tried adding the above non-clustered index and have found some noticeable improvement.

- SQL Server version: SQL Server 2008 Standard
- .NET Framework 4.0
- OS : Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

On the production server, there are about 300,000+ records and when we insert row by row from the .net application (Windows service) with the condition in place, it only inserts 10 to 20 rows per minute. If we remove the condition check, then the number of rows inserted goes to 300 to 400+ rows per min. We have also tried adding/removing the above non-clustered index but haven't found any noticeable improvement.

Hence, we kept it disable for now. Interestingly, if we run the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio for inserting 1 record, there is no issue, we have also checked the actual execution plan there is no table scan happening nor the stored procedure is taking any time.

- SQL Server version: SQL Server 2012 Standard SP3
- .NET Framework 4.0
- OS : Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Other performance tuning activities rebuild, reorganize, update statistics, stored procedure recompile and parameter sniffing has also been tried. However, nothing seems to work.

We are in a fix now. We are unable to find any alternative. It would helpful if you can provide us some suggestion/guidance.

Thanks in advance.
Ujjal

Comment: You forgot to post your SQL statement! We can't help you make a query faster without the query!!! :) The DDL of the tables and indexes will also help people (don't list the columns, provide `CREATE` statements). You can also provide the **actual** execution plan by using [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: If you notice a difference in performance between production code and running the code in SSMS then take a look at http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html.

Comment: Just guessing but maybe extending the unique index to include `Id` as well, like putting it on `(Id, MessageId, MessageTime, ControllerId, InterfaceHardwareId, IDType, MapId)` might be worth a try.

Answer (score 4):

Add a unique **constraint** not an index, as in:

```
alter table AlarmLog add constraint uq_alarmlog_row unique (
  MessageId, MessageTime, ControllerId, 
  InterfaceHardwareId, IDType, MapId);
```

This will automatically reject an insertion of a new row whose values match this column combination exactly.

This should also be fast in terms of performance. No need to call a procedure to run a previous `select` and check the values existence.

Just run a simple SQL `insert` and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your production environment is near a bandwidth cap. Due to other operation that are currently running in it. the amount of queries that are being process is putting your network into saturation.